# How to make knn faster?

Tags: python, time-series, classification, knn

I have a dataset of shape(700000,20) and I want to apply KNN to it.

However on testing it takes really huge time,can someone expert please help to let me know how can I reduce the KNN predicting time.

Is there something like GPU-KNN or something.Please help to let me know.

Below is the code I am using.

```
import os 
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from joblib import load, dump
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from dtaidistance import dtw


window_length = 20
n = 5


X_train = load('X_train.pth').reshape(-1,20)
y_train = load('y_train.pth').reshape(-1)
X_test = load('X_test.pth').reshape(-1,20)
y_test = load('y_test.pth').reshape(-1)


#custom metric
def DTW(a, b):   
    return dtw.distance(a, b)


clf = KNeighborsClassifier(metric=DTW)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


#evaluate
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: Did you actually profile your code? Yes, KNN is usually slow. Still, I can bet that most of the compute time is spent evaluating your `DTW` metric...

Comment: If I am trying without the BTW metric it is still taking much more time in euclidean distance metric.

Comment: "much more time" compared to what?
In any event, if you look at the options of `KNeighborsClassifier`, then you should obviously test setting the `algorithm` explicitly to `'ball_tree'` or `'kd_tree'` and `n_jobs` to your number of cores.

Comment: I tried with normal distance again and it seems it is running fine... Yes DTW metric is taking too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metric dtw is taking too much time while simple knn is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest reducing the number of features which i think its 20 features from your dataset shape, Which mean you have 20 dimensions.

You can reduce the number of features by using PCA (Principal Component Analysis) like the following:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA    
train_data_pca = PCA(n_components=10)
reduced_train_data = train_data_pca.fit_transform(train_data)
```

this code will reduce deminisions for example to 10 instead of 20

Second issue in your code, that I see that you are not using th K neighboors value in the classifier, It should be as the following:

```
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n, metric=DTW)
```